# Why my MariaDB sequence generates a negative number?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, mariadb, sequence-generators

I'm running the latest `MariaDB 10.3.7` server which offers sequences.

I created my sequences as:

```
drop sequence if exists user_account_id_seq;
create sequence user_account_id_seq;
drop table if exists user_account;
create table user_account (
  -- id bigint(20) unsigned not null auto_increment,
  id bigint(20) unsigned not null default (next value for user_account_id_seq),
  version int(10) unsigned not null,
  firstname varchar(255) not null,
  lastname varchar(255) not null,
  password varchar(100),
  password_salt varchar(50),
  readable_password varchar(50),
  email varchar(50) not null,
  confirmed_email bit(1) not null check (confirmed_email in (0, 1)),
  work_phone varchar(20),
  unique key email (email),
  primary key (id)
);

drop sequence if exists user_role_id_seq;
create sequence user_role_id_seq;
drop table if exists user_role;
create table user_role (
  -- id bigint(20) unsigned not null auto_increment,
  id bigint(20) unsigned not null default (next value for user_role_id_seq),
  version int(10) unsigned not null,
  user_account_id bigint(20) unsigned not null,
  role varchar(50) not null,
  unique key user_role_u1 (user_account_id, role),
  key user_account_id (user_account_id),
  constraint user_role_fk1 foreign key (user_account_id) references user_account (id),
  primary key (id)
);
```

Which looks like:

```
MariaDB [useraccounttest]> show create sequence user_account_id_seq;
+---------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table               | Create Table                                                                                                                               |
+---------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| user_account_id_seq | CREATE SEQUENCE `user_account_id_seq` start with 1 minvalue 1 maxvalue 9223372036854775806 increment by 1 cache 1000 nocycle ENGINE=InnoDB |
+---------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I wonder why my sequence generates a negative number:

```
19:16:42.294 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener - Generated identifier: -29, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator
```

I'm using the dialoect `org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB103Dialect`.

Here is the configuration:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "id_generator")
@Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private Long id;
...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_account")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "id_generator", sequenceName = "user_account_id_seq")
public class User extends AbstractEntity {
...
}
```

Here are my properties:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB103Dialect
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=net.sf.log4jdbc.DriverSpy
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:log4jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/useraccounttest?serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=useraccount
spring.datasource.password=mypassword
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

The console log chunk:

```
19:16:42.294 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Participating in existing transaction
19:16:42.294 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener - Generated identifier: -29, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator
19:16:42.295 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Processing flush-time cascades
19:16:42.295 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Dirty checking collections
19:16:42.295 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections - Collection found: [com.thalasoft.userdata.jpa.domain.User.userRoles#-29], was: [<unreferenced>] (initialized)
19:16:42.295 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 1 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 1 objects
19:16:42.295 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 1 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 1 collections
19:16:42.295 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter - Listing entities:
19:16:42.296 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter - com.thalasoft.userdata.jpa.domain.User{userRoles=[], firstname=Stephane, password=toto, readablePassword=null, confirmedEmail=false, workPhone=null, id=-29, version=0, passwordSalt=, email=component[value]{value=stephane@thalasoft.com}, lastname=Eybert}
19:16:42.296 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - insert into user_account (version, confirmed_email, email, firstname, lastname, password, password_salt, readable_password, work_phone, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into user_account (version, confirmed_email, email, firstname, lastname, password, password_salt, readable_password, work_phone, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
19:16:42.297 [main] DEBUG jdbc.audit - 1. PreparedStatement.new PreparedStatement returned   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:318)
19:16:42.302 [main] DEBUG jdbc.audit - 1. Connection.prepareStatement(insert into user_account (version, confirmed_email, email, firstname, lastname, password, password_salt, readable_password, work_phone, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)) returned net.sf.log4jdbc.PreparedStatementSpy@44bc2449  com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:318)
19:16:42.302 [main] DEBUG jdbc.audit - 1. PreparedStatement.setInt(1, 0) returned   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.setInt(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java:-1)
19:16:42.303 [main] DEBUG jdbc.audit - 1. PreparedStatement.setBoolean(2, false) returned   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.setBoolean(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java:-1)
19:16:42.303 [main] DEBUG jdbc.audit - 1. PreparedStatement.setString(3, "stephane@thalasoft.com") returned   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.setString(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java:-1)
19:16:42.303 [main] DEBUG jdbc.audit - 1. PreparedStatement.setString(4, "Stephane") returned   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.setString(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java:-1)
19:16:42.304 [main] DEBUG jdbc.audit - 1. PreparedStatement.setString(5, "Eybert") returned   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.setString(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java:-1)
19:16:42.304 [main] DEBUG jdbc.audit - 1. PreparedStatement.setString(6, "toto") returned   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.setString(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java:-1)
19:16:42.304 [main] DEBUG jdbc.audit - 1. PreparedStatement.setString(7, "") returned   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.setString(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java:-1)
19:16:42.304 [main] DEBUG jdbc.audit - 1. PreparedStatement.setNull(8, 12) returned   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.setNull(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java:-1)
19:16:42.305 [main] DEBUG jdbc.audit - 1. PreparedStatement.setNull(9, 12) returned   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.setNull(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java:-1)
19:16:42.305 [main] DEBUG jdbc.audit - 1. PreparedStatement.setLong(10, -29) returned   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.setLong(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java:-1)
19:16:42.305 [main] DEBUG jdbc.sqlonly -  com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
1. insert into user_account (version, confirmed_email, email, firstname, lastname, password, password_salt, 
readable_password, work_phone, id) values (0, 0, 'stephane@thalasoft.com', 'Stephane', 'Eybert', 
'toto', '', NULL, NULL, -29) 

19:16:42.307 [main] ERROR jdbc.audit - 1. PreparedStatement.executeUpdate() insert into user_account (version, confirmed_email, email, firstname, lastname, password, password_salt, 
readable_password, work_phone, id) values (0, 0, 'stephane@thalasoft.com', 'Stephane', 'Eybert', 
'toto', '', NULL, NULL, -29) 

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Out of range value for column 'id' at row 1
```

Comment: I would recommend opening a bug report about this on the [MariaDB Jira](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV).

Comment: The JIRA is filed at `https://jira.mariadb.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/MDEV-16628`